# Lifecycle of a Layout (or Component) in Vaadin?

Tags: java, layout, vaadin, lifecycle, vaadin7

What hooks do I have into the lifecycle of a Layout specifically, or Component generally in Vaadin 7?

## Lifecycle Events?

I want to know when a Layout is starting (being born) and stopping (dying). Specifically, I suspect I really care about "attach" and "detach". The Layout could exist off screen before use on-screen and even afterwards if I might re-display that Layout later in the user’s work session. I think attachment is that process of joining/leaving the displayed UI, but I’m not sure.

## Motivation: Notification, in Observer Pattern

Not that it matters, but the reason I care about the lifecycle is shown in the [Push page](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.push.html) of the [Book of Vaadin 7](https://vaadin.com/book). As seen there, I want to notify a bunch of users’ Layouts (in UIs) about a change in the data represented by their widgets. So each Layout needs to have a method invoked, to make them update their widgets with fresh data.

To notify each Layout, I need to know which Layout instances exist and are interested in this kind of update. So I keep a collection of Layouts that register themselves. Basically, the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). That Push page shows such a registry collection.

The missing piece: Where in the Layout's code do I make the Layout instance register and unregister? I suppose I could the Java constructor and `finalize` method. But I suspect I really want registration to revolve around the attach and detach events.

## Attach/Detach Events

The [`Layout`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Layout.html) doc lists many attach/detach listeners and `attach`/`detach` methods. I'm not sure which I should be using, if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your assumptions are correct.  when a component gets the parent set it is attached to the UI (or in general the session).  so this component is relevant for the client (yet it might not be visible right now in the client).

one way to deal with this is overriding [`attach()`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Component.html#attach()) and/or `detach()` to fire your logic to register/deregister.

or by adding listeners for attach and detach: [AttachListener](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/ClientConnector.AttachListener.html) for [addAttachListener](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/AbstractClientConnector.html#addAttachListener%28com.vaadin.server.ClientConnector.AttachListener%29)

```
    def layout = new VerticalLayout()
    layout.addAttachListener(new ClientConnector.AttachListener() {
        @Override
        void attach(ClientConnector.AttachEvent attachEvent) {
            println "Attach: $attachEvent"
        }
    })
    layout.addDetachListener(new ClientConnector.DetachListener() {
        @Override
        void detach(ClientConnector.DetachEvent detachEvent) {
            println "Detach: $detachEvent"
        }
    })
```

Comment: Really, is it as simple as overriding `attach` and `detach`? Also, if I am not subclassing a Layout, is there a way to subscribe as a listener to the attachment/detachment events? I did see some such methods in the doc, but they confused me.

Comment: @BasilBourque i have added the parts about the listeners to the answer